# Different values of same variable at different places in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jquery an i am trying to get some data through ajax.
 **Here is the code**

```
$(function () {
     var allProductsData;
     var gotProducts = new Array();
     var productsWithDelete = new Array();
     $('.addProducts').on('keyup', function (event) {
         var searchVal = $(this).val().trim();
         if (searchVal.length > 0) {
             $.ajax({
                 url: 'http://localhost/exhibition/admin/default/searchProducts',
                 data: {
                     products: $(this).val(),
                 },
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'html',
                 success: function (msg) {
                     allProductsData = msg;
                     alert(allProductsData); //No. 1 
                 }
             });
             alert(allProductsData); //No. 2
         }
         alert(allProductsData); // No. 3
     });
 });
```

The value i am getting back from the server is `1`. As you can see that i have stored that value in a global variable `allProductsData`. But when i try to alert this **allProductsData** at 3 different places (No 1, No 2, No 3). then I get different values i.e 
`1` at **No 1** // which is correct
**undefined** at No 2 // which is incorrect
**1** at No 3 // which is again correct
**Question**
Why I am getting the **undefined** value there?

Comment: because ajax is asynch

Comment: @Tomanow This has nothing to do with scope. The scope is entirely correct. Some alert lines are just evaluated earlier than the callback, which is why the variable is still `undefined`.

Comment: When using `alert` in situations like that, it's better to mark the calls with some prefix so you are sure what call is processed. Example: `alert("No.1 value=" + allProductsData);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A in AJAX stands for Asynchronous, therefore you can't opperate on normal synchronouse calls. Alert `No 1.` is called after receiving response from server, it might, but also may not, be called before Alert `No 2.`. Then, `No 2.` is called and have not guarantee that it has already assigned value from ajax call.
The `No 3.` I believe, has it's correct value because after calling `No 1.` and `No 2.` your server managed to respond to you with correct value.

In order to receive always correct value, operate on response in success function callback.

Answer (score 1):

The only place that you can be sure to have defined the `allProductsData` is in the `success` callback. The code after the ajax call will be evaluated once the call has been sent, not when a response has been received.

You should put all the code that needs `allProductsData` in a function an call that in the `success` callback. Otherwise you can never be sure that `allProductsData` is defined.